# sharepoint 2010 Retention Policy not working?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created one simple document library and want to enable a retention policy for that, for this thing I have created one document library and have navigated to following steps:

1) Document Library Settings --> Information management policy settings

2) selected the "Document" as Content Type.

3) Checked on "Enable Retention",

4) Click on "Add a retention stage"

5) here I defined that "Date Created" + 1 " Day", should need to move in recycle bin.

According to above defined policy the documents which are created date spent on more than one day should automatically move to recycle bin, but it is not moving or doing anything, does anything help me in this context? That does i need to enable from Cetral Administration or enable any feature or need to do something more to allow that policy to work fine?? 
I have multiple documents in the library that have a created date over the 3 days. How often is the retention policy run? daily? weekly?

Comment: SharePoint related questions would be very welcome on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) - you might want to consider posting it there, or better still asking for it to be migrated.

Answer (score 20):

Few things you have to follow here:

1. Go to `Top level site settings->Under Site Collection Administration->Site Collection features->Activate "Library and Folder Based Retention"`.
2. `"Information management policy"` and `"Expiration policy"` are the 2 timer jobs which are responsible for retention policy. By default both will work `"Weekly"` change it to `"Daily"` in `Central Admin -> Monitoring ->Review job definitions-> Find "Information management policy" and "Expiration policy"`.

*Note*: Set the `Recurring Schedule` in such a way that `"Information management policy"` job should run before the `"Expiration policy"`.

Test it by setting your retention policy for a document library.

Answer (score 0):

Under point 1, you need to go to site settings->Under Site Collection Administration->Site Collection FEATURES and there activate the "Library and Folder Based Retention" feature